# Path Traversal Vulnerability fix problems Android

Tags: android, android-security

While recently submitting a app it got rejected saying
Vulnerability: Path Traversal
Your app(s) are using a content provider with an unsafe implementation of openFile.
Google suggested two solutions to fix this issue
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7496913

One is to set android:exported=false and other is to check the canonical path

```
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile (Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
 File f = new File(DIR, uri.getLastPathSegment());
 if (!f.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(DIR)) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }
 return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}
```

When I execute this it always enter the if condition and throws error as I observed that

- Absolute path = DIR + lastPathSegment

but the canonical path never starts with DIR where DIR is

```
String DIR = getContext().getCacheDir().toString();
```

The result I got for each is

- DIR = /data/user/0/newOrg/cache
- Absolute Path =
  /data/user/0/newOrg/cache/123.html
- Canonical Path =
  /data/data/newOrg/cache/123.html

How do I fix the Path Traversal Vulnerability if the Canonical Path doesn't start with DIR?

Answer (score 0):

canonicalize your DIR first

```kotlin
  val invalid = Uri.parse("foo:///hello/${URLEncoder.encode("../user.txt", "UTF-8")}")
  val valid = Uri.parse("foo:///hello/../hello.txt")

  val root = cacheDir.canonicalFile
  val validPath = File(root, valid.lastPathSegment).canonicalFile
  val invalidPath = File(root, invalid.lastPathSegment).canonicalFile

  // root -> /data/data/play.ground/cache
  Log.e(TAG, "root -> $root")

  // validPath -> /data/data/play.ground/cache/hello.txt
  Log.e(TAG, "validPath -> $validPath")

  // invalidPath -> /data/data/play.ground/user.txt
  Log.e(TAG, "invalidPath -> $invalidPath")


  // note the `/` suffix below, it's also essential
  assert(validPath.absolutePath.startsWith(root.absolutePath + "/")) 
  assert(!invalidPath.absolutePath.startsWith(root.absolutePath + "/"))
```

Bonus, most parts of `Uri` will decode the String value, like below, so handle with care

```kotlin
private val String.e
  get() = URLEncoder.encode(this, "UTF-8")

val url = Uri.parse("sch${"/../".e}me://ho${"/../".e}st/pa${"/../".e}th/last${"/../".e}path")
  Log.e(
            TAG,
            "url: $url, \nscheme:${url.scheme}, \nhost:${url.host}, \npath:${url.path} \npathSegments:${url.pathSegments}, \nlastPathSegments:${url.lastPathSegment}"
)

/*
url: sch%2F..%2Fme://ho%2F..%2Fst/pa%2F..%2Fth/last%2F..%2Fpath,                                                                                                     

scheme:sch%2F..%2Fme,                                                                                                     

host:ho/../st,                                                                                                     

path:/pa/../th/last/../path                                                                                                     

pathSegments:[pa/../th, last/../path],                                                                                                     

lastPathSegments:last/../path
*/
```